# Is it possible to have construct two regular tetrahedrons of side length $s$ such that their heights coincide?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to have construct two regular tetrahedrons of side length $s$ such that their heights coincide (vertex to center of base) coincide but not the tetrahedrons themselves? I can construct two such that one of their heights coincide simply by inverting one of the tetrahedrons but is it possible to have all their heights coincide?

Comment: All regular tetrahedra of the same side length are congruent.

Answer (score 3):

If "heights coincide" means "altitude *segments* coincide" (that is, these altitudes have the same endpoints), then it's pretty easy to see that only way to get four coincident heights (or even just more than one) from two congruent regular tetrahedra is to have the tetrahedra coincide.

If "heights coincide" means "altitude *lines* coincide", then two non-coincident, congruent regular tetrahedra can have four coincident heights: simply "reflect" the vertices in the tetrahedron's center to get the companion tetrahedron's vertices. The resulting configuration is called a ["compound of two (regular) tetrahedra"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_of_two_tetrahedra).

When you realize that a collection of four "non-adjacent" vertices of a cube serve as vertices of a regular tetrahedron (the edges of the tetrahedron are diagonals of the cube's faces), it's easier to see that the "other" four vertices *also* serve as the vertices of a regular tetrahedron, and that this pair of tetrahedra are in the arrangement you seek. The shared altitude-lines are the (body-)diagonal-lines of the cube.